# Изменение функции main

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

```
from collections import Counter


def sleight_of_hand(k2, matrix):
    c = Counter(int(x) for row in matrix for x in row if x != ".")
    return sum(x <= k2 for x in c.values())


def main():
    k2 = 2 * int(input())
    matrix = (input() for _ in range(4))
    result = sleight_of_hand(k2, matrix)
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Мне сказали, что `def main()` - лишняя промежуточная функция, и код можно сразу написать под `if __name__ == '__main__'`
Но если я его пишу после  `if __name__ == '__main__'` код перестает работать. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Не слушайте "умников". Инкапсуляция main делает программу лучше и чище

Comment: `def main` - не лишняя. Без неё переменные вроде `k2` становятся глобальными, они видны во всех остальных функциях. Нечаянное обращение к такому имени в другой функции проходит не замеченым, имеем баг. После третьего такого бага не оставляю никаких глобальных имён кроме того что импортируется и имён функций. Не слушайте в данном случае советчиков, main нужен и полезен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам перенесенный код, ещё и под PEP-8 исправленный. Так как вы свой переделанный не привели, то ошибку не укажу. Сравнивайте и смотрите, что у вас не так было.

И @eri и @Stanislav Volodarskiy правы, первый код лучше, если не учитель так потребовал, то лучше не менять.

```
from collections import Counter


def sleight_of_hand(k2, matrix):
    c = Counter(int(x) for row in matrix for x in row if x != ".")
    return sum(x <= k2 for x in c.values())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    k2 = 2 * int(input())
    matrix = (input() for _ in range(4))
    result = sleight_of_hand(k2, matrix)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Что-то я в упор не вижу в чём собственно проблема была ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, например, можно перенести без отступа, можно перенести вместе с `def`, убрав вызов `main()`. Но теперь в базе знаний есть два варианта, как делать `main`:-)